# Facebook Graph API - upload photo using JavaScript with base64 image URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

The following code snippet is used to upload photo using facebook Javascript SDK. Can I use the imgURL to be base64 image URL string which is generated from Canvas? Something like "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUh..."

```
var imgURL="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3332/3451193407_b7f047f4b4_o.jpg";//change with your external photo url
FB.api('/album_id/photos', 'post', {
    message:'photo description',
    url:imgURL        
}, function(response){

    if (!response || response.error) {
        alert('Error occured');
    } else {
        alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
    }

});
```

Comment: No, I am using backend PHP to do this.

Comment: i think it's possible, just need to use multipart/form-data in the body of request. see here: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/

Comment: Since the Facebook JavaScript SDK documentation talks about an URL and not a data-URL, I would say the answer is: No.

But how did you managed to do this by PHP SDK?

Comment: I converted the base64 data-URL string to binary data and created an image file on the server and uploaded the same.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to upload the base64 data URL to imgur or Amazon S3, then post the returned URL to facebook:
http://alipman88.github.io/debt/about/index.html

Alternative solution using only JavaScript (haven't tested personally):
[Upload Base64 Image Facebook Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16214300/upload-base64-image-facebook-graph-api)