# Upload Base64 Image Facebook Graph API

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook-graph-api, encoding, base64

I'm trying to upload a base64 image to a FaceBook page using Node.js. I have managed to get the upload working with all the multipart data etc should I read the file from the filesystem (ie. using fs.readFileSync('c:\a.jpg')

However, should I use the base64 encoded image and try upload it, it give me the following error : `{"error":{"message":"(#1) An unknown error occurred","type":"OAuthException","code":1}}`

I have tried converting it to binary by `new Buffer(b64string, 'base64');` and uploading that, but no luck.

I have been struggling with this for 3 days now, so anyhelp would be greatly appreciated.

Edit : If anyone also knows how I could convert the base64 to binary and successfully upload it, that would also work for me.

Edit : Code Snippet

```
var postDetails = separator + newlineConstant + 'Content-Disposition: form-data;name="access_token"' + newlineConstant + newlineConstant + accessToken + newlineConstant + separator;

postDetails = postDetails + newlineConstant + 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="message"' + newlineConstant + newlineConstant + message + newlineConstant;

//Add the Image information
var fileDetailsString = '';
var index = 0;
var multipartBody = new Buffer(0);
images.forEach(function (currentImage) {
    fileDetailsString = fileDetailsString + separator + newlineConstant + 'Content-Disposition: file; name="source"; filename="Image' + index + '"' + newlineConstant + 'Content-Type: image/jpeg' + newlineConstant + newlineConstant;
    index++;

    multipartBody = Buffer.concat([multipartBody, new Buffer(fileDetailsString), currentImage]); //This is what I would use if Bianry data was passed in 

    currentImage = new Buffer (currentImage.toString('base64'), 'base64'); // The following lines are what I would use for base64 image being passed in (The appropriate lines would be enabled/disabled if I was using Binary/base64)
    multipartBody = Buffer.concat([multipartBody, new Buffer(fileDetailsString), currentImage]);
});

multipartBody = Buffer.concat([new Buffer(postDetails), multipartBody, new Buffer(footer)]);
```

Comment: Where is the b64String coming from? Are you sure it's not a data URL? Please show some example data if you `console.log(b64string)`.

Comment: Could you provide any sample of uploading base64 through javascript ajax.

Comment: Hey guys, sorry for the late reply...been away.

it definitely isn't a data URL...here is a snippet of the beginning of the data.../9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/2wBDABcQERQRDhcUEhQaGBcbIjk

@Brune I have updated the post to put a snippet of the upload section. The multipart data etc all works as when I have a binary image passed it all works 100% but when I have a base64 image passed in it doesn't work.

Comment: Does this related to Node.js.. I've base64 image data and struck with the structure of ajax request(what should go in header and body).. I've got Invalid request error..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The code above didn't quite work for me (Missing comma after `type:"POST",` and data URI to blob function reported errors. I got the following code to work in Firefox and Chrome:

```
function PostImageToFacebook(authToken)
{
    var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
    var imageData  = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    try {
        blob = dataURItoBlob(imageData);
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("access_token",authToken);
    fd.append("source", blob);
    fd.append("message","Photo Text");
    try {
        $.ajax({
            url:"https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=" + authToken,
            type:"POST",
            data:fd,
            processData:false,
            contentType:false,
            cache:false,
            success:function(data){
                console.log("success " + data);
            },
            error:function(shr,status,data){
                console.log("error " + data + " Status " + shr.status);
            },
            complete:function(){
                console.log("Posted to facebook");
            }
        });
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
    var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
    var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return new Blob([ab], { type: 'image/png' });
}
```

Here's the code at GitHub
https://github.com/DanBrown180/html5-canvas-post-to-facebook-base64

Comment: I've tried your code out and my communication w Facebook seems to be working, but I have an issue that the fd (FormData) is empty, just showing empty arrays.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 24):

I hope this will be useful. By doing photo upload to FB only with the help of javascript you can use the following method. Required thing here are imageData(which is base64 format of image) and the mime type.

```
try {
    blob = dataURItoBlob(imageData,mimeType);
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}

var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("access_token",accessToken);
fd.append("source", blob);
fd.append("message","Kiss");

try {
   $.ajax({
        url:"https://graph.facebook.com/" + <<userID received on getting user details>> + "/photos?access_token=" + <<user accessToken>>,
        type:"POST",
        data:fd,
        processData:false,
        contentType:false,
        cache:false,
        success:function(data){
            console.log("success " + data);
        },
        error:function(shr,status,data){
            console.log("error " + data + " Status " + shr.status);
        },
        complete:function(){
            console.log("Ajax Complete");
        }
   });

} catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
}

function dataURItoBlob(dataURI,mime) {
    // convert base64 to raw binary data held in a string
    // doesn't handle URLEncoded DataURIs

    var byteString = window.atob(dataURI);

    // separate out the mime component


    // write the bytes of the string to an ArrayBuffer
    //var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
    var ia = new Uint8Array(byteString.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    // write the ArrayBuffer to a blob, and you're done
    var blob = new Blob([ia], { type: mime });

    return blob;
}
```

//EDIT AJAX SYNTAX

Comment: Did you get this to work? I couldn't get a correct response. And for the dataURI, do you remove the "data:image/png;base64," part?

Comment: Yeah. It is working fine. Yes, you've to remove the "data:image/png;base64," portion when you send it for blob conversion.

Comment: Holy, moly. This worked! Should have tweaked it more before complaining here. You're a miracle worker!

Comment: Hope someone sees this! Am attempting the same thing, but I seem to always be receiving an error back from Facebook with my FormData showing empty arrays.  Any ideas??!

Comment: What error are you receiving?? Do you mean to say your formdata is not  passed to facebook??

Comment: I have tried use `FB.api()` but without success. And now, I tested this code and works! Hell yeaaah! Thanks :)

Comment: I am using this code and always get an error from Facebook saying 'Bad Request'. Any ideas?

Comment: did you remove the data identification portion of your base64 content "data:image/png:base64"??

Comment: Ths one works, i also used this many ways .
The hot is the "dataURItoBlob", BLOB, thats the keyword :P

Answer (score 2):

Dan's Answer works the best. Something else that might be helpful in this scenario is the optional argument for posting photos: 'no_story'. This arg defaults to true forcing the photo-post to skip the user's wall. By adding

```
fd.append("no_story", false);
```

you can update the user's wall with the photo-post.

I would have just left this as a comment but... 50 Rep for comments.

Comment: That sounds like an important feature! And hey... you need to spend more time here!

Answer (score 2):

We can simplify image recoding by usage of the modern Fetch API instead of Uint8Array.

```
 var url = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="

 fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.blob())
  .then(blob => console.log(blob))`
```

Comment: The only problem with this is that it's an experimental feature (https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_body_blob). So be careful when using it in production.

Answer (score 1):

I did something very similar to your question. I had a webcam-snapshot that needed to be POSTed to a Facebook Fan Page. 
The setup was in a restaurant where people could take a picture and it would be posted onto the Restaurants Page. People would then see a QR code to the posted facebook-photo which they could choose to share on their own profile. 
Hope this can help somebody because I searched a lot to get to this working SOLUTION

**Note:** My image is BASE64 encoded already.

```
//imageData is a base64 encoded JPG
function postSocial(imageData, message){       
        var ia = toUInt8Array(imageData);
        postImageToFacebook(mAccessTokenPage, "imageName", "image/jpeg",ia, message);
}

function toUInt8Array(dataURI) {
        // convert base64 to raw binary data held in a string
        // doesn't handle URLEncoded DataURIs
        var byteString = window.atob(dataURI);

        // write the bytes of the string to an ArrayBuffer
        //var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
        var ia = new Uint8Array(byteString.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
            ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        return ia;
    }

function postImageToFacebook( authToken, filename, mimeType, imageData, message ) {        
        // this is the multipart/form-data boundary we'll use
        var boundary = '----ThisIsTheBoundary1234567890';

        // let's encode our image file, which is contained in the var
        var formData = '--' + boundary + '\r\n'
        formData += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="source"; filename="' + filename + '"\r\n';
        formData += 'Content-Type: ' + mimeType + '\r\n\r\n';
        for ( var i = 0; i < imageData.length; ++i )
        {
            formData += String.fromCharCode( imageData[ i ] & 0xff );
        }
        formData += '\r\n';
        formData += '--' + boundary + '\r\n';
        formData += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="message"\r\n\r\n';
        formData += message + '\r\n'
        formData += '--' + boundary + '--\r\n';

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open( 'POST', https://graph.facebook.com/ + {PAGE_ID} + "/photos?access_token=" + authToken, true );
        xhr.onload = function() {
            // ... Fill in your own
            //Image was posted 
           console.log(xhr.responseText);
        };
        xhr.onerror = function(){
            console.log("Error while sending the image to Facebook");
        };
        xhr.setRequestHeader( "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary );
        xhr.sendAsBinary( formData );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I was able to post an image to facebook using the facebook JS API.
I am using the canvas HTML5 functionality. It's not fully supported by every browser.

You need first to get the image data. Then to encapsulate it in a form data.
I then use the FB.login API in order to retrieve the access token and the userID.

```
          var data = $('#map >> canvas').toDataURL('image/png');
          var blob;
          try {
            var byteString = atob(data.split(',')[1]);
            var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
            var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
            for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
              ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
            }
            blob = new Blob([ab], {type: 'image/png'});
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
          }
          var fd = new FormData();
          fd.append("source", blob);
          fd.append("message", "Photo Text");
          FB.login(function(){
            var auth = FB.getAuthResponse();
            $.ajax({
              url:"https://graph.facebook.com/"+auth.userID+"/photos?access_token=" + auth.accessToken,
              type:"POST",
              data:fd,
              processData:false,
              contentType:false,
              cache:false,
              success:function(data){
                console.log("success " + data);
              },
              error:function(shr,status,data){
                console.log("error " + data + " Status " + shr.status);
              },
              complete:function(){
                console.log("Ajax Complete");
              }
            });
          }, {scope: 'publish_actions'});
```

Comment: This is great as you show us how to get the actual authorization parameters to contact Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that does not need jQuery or other libraries, just the native Fetch API:

```
const dataURItoBlob = (dataURI) => {
    let byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    let ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
    let ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
    for (let i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return new Blob([ia], {
        type: 'image/jpeg'
    });
}
const upload = async (response) => {
    let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    let dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);
    let blob = dataURItoBlob(dataURL);
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('access_token', response.authResponse.accessToken);
    formData.append('source', blob);

    let responseFB = await fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos`, {
        body: formData,
        method: 'post'
    });
    responseFB = await responseFB.json();
    console.log(responseFB);
};
document.getElementById('upload').addEventListener('click', () => {
    FB.login((response) => {
        //TODO check if user is logged in and authorized publish_actions
        upload(response);
    }, {scope: 'publish_actions'})
})
```

Source: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-photo-upload-from-canvas/