# How to add remote upload functionality to a web app with Instagram-like Filters to allow sharing on Facebook?

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

I found this awesome tutorial on building a web app with instagram-like filters:
http://tutorialzine.com/2013/02/enhancing-the-instragram-filter-app/

The app allows you to drag a picture from your computer into the browser and apply instagram-like filters to it. Then you can download the image to your computer.

I am trying to figure out how to add the ability to share the photo on Facebook. Is it possible to do it without a remote upload?

I have one idea of using this script:

```
<a class="share" onclick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[title]=Title_Goes_Here&amp;p[summary]=Copy_Goes_Here&amp;p[url]=http://www.website.com&amp;&amp;p[images][0]=http://www.webste.com/image_url.jpg', 'newwindow', 'width=555, height=315'); return false;"></a>
```

Would it be possible to replace the "http://www.webste.com/image_url.jpg" part with the temporary image that is generated by the canvas?

Thanks so much!

Comment: You can use blob to upload directly the image without saving (decoding the base64 string into an image on the server), see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16439233/2151050)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is not possible.

The only way to pass the image directly in the URL would be to create a Data URI. While canvas does have a toDataURL() method to get such a representation of an image, share.php most likely does not support passing that and expects a normal URL. Even if it did, such a long URL for window.open would probably break on some browsers, at least older IE versions that seem to have around 2kB URL length limit.

One thing you might be able to do though is upload the image directly to Facebook by getting the user to log in to Facebook with the appropriate privileges and then POSTing to https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos, but I have not tried that from Javascript.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try to use the log in option.