# facebook feed dialog share dataURL

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, html5-canvas, data-url

I would like for the user to share client side image on facebook with the feed dialog or other approach

```
FB.ui({ method: 'feed',
caption: 'Mega Tangram Picture',
message: 'I made this tangram picture on MegaTangram',
picture: canvas.toDataURL("image/png;base64;")
}, function(response){console.log(response);});
```

Its not working with the `dataURL` standard, is there another way to do this (graph api?), it must be possible to share dynamically created images that are not held on the server?

The error I got was:

```
An error occurred. Please try again later.

API Error Code: 100
API Error Description: Invalid parameter
Error Message: picture URL is not properly formatted

checkupdatefeed result parameter= undefined script.js:1183
checkupdatefeed result parameter= 1390679958266:9.4.0
```

When trying with `image/jpeg;base64`, I get the following error:

```
Could not find callback 1
```

Comment: You can try this one https://coderwall.com/p/4qpmfw but I have never done something similar

Comment: @dachi it seems that this is for uploading images to the user photos, not for sharing on the feed.

Comment: that looks good however I am getting the following error when making the post as if facebook only allows these kind of posts from a php environment!

{
   "error": {
      "message": "API calls from the server require an appsecret_proof argument",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100
   }
}

Comment: there are maybe better examples here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16214300/upload-base64-image-facebook-graph-api/16439233#16439233

but they all fail with the message

API calls from the server require an appsecret_proof argument

I have no Idea how to get round this in a client side FB call!

Comment: You may be able to disable the appsecret_proof requirement for testing purposes, see here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/securing-requests/#require-proof

Comment: Yes the appsecret proof was stopping the code from working which I disabled from within the app settings, it also worked when I used the hashed appsecret code returned from my server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, it's not possible. When you share something in the feed, Facebook needs to be able to fetch the image from a public URL.

> **picture**: The **URL** of a picture attached to this post.

Source: [Feed and Share Dialogs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/)

You need to upload the image somewhere first (for instance [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/fr/s3/)).

Answer (score 0):

You can upload your canvas image to dropbox and then use the generated url in facebook feed url - [Save image to dropbox with data from canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27524283/save-image-to-dropbox-with-data-from-canvas)